# Saving values until specific tag appear

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have html which have that tags for example:

```
h2
span
span
span
h2
span
span
h2
span
span
span
span
```

I want to save it to excel file so I wrote that loop which get h2/span tags at once:

```
for item in soup.find_all(re.compile(r'^(h2|span)$'), {'class': re.compile(r'^(product-name|attribute-value)$')}):
```

How can I make it to save h2, then span on the same row until next h2 appears, and saving it to next row, etc. I'm using openpyxl for .xlsx files.

It should look like this:

```
h2 span span span
h2 span span
h2 span span span span
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `find_all`, iterate over the tags using `find_next`. Based on the tag, relevant action can be executed

```
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active

    tagiterator = soup.h2

    row, col = 1, 1
    ws.cell(row=row, column=col, value=tagiterator.getText())
    tagiterator = tagiterator.find_next()
    while tagiterator.find_next():
        if tagiterator.name == 'h2':
            # Go to the next line
            row += 1
            col = 1
            ws.cell(row=row, column=col, value=tagiterator.getText())
        elif tagiterator.name == 'span':
            # Go to the next column
            col += 1
            ws.cell(row=row, column=col, value=tagiterator.getText())
        tagiterator = tagiterator.find_next()
    wb.save('sample.xlsx')
```

Comment: It helped me with my problem, thanks! But I need one more thing; How can I make this to save only these h2 tags which have 'product-name' value of the class, and span which have 'attribute-value' value of the class. I tried to do this with .get, .has_attr, another if statement and none of them worked.

Comment: You can directly 'index' into it. For example if `<h2 class='testclass'> Hello World </h2>` was the html, after you soupify it, you can access the tag as `soup.h2['class']`

Comment: Not working properly for me. I changed the if and elif statements to look like this: 
    `if tagiterator['class'] == 'product-name':
    elif tagiterator['class'] == 'attribute-value':`

There is image with marked things what I want to achieve:
[link](https://ibb.co/eWLsoQ)

And there is a page: [link](http://www.euro.com.pl/telewizory-led-lcd-plazmowe,strona-1.bhtml)